# Filtering on a dataframe based on columns defined in a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe - 
df

```
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|T1_diff|T2_diff|
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|     -5|     60|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|     90|      4|
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
```

I have defined a list as targetList

```
List(T1_diff, T2_diff)
```

I want to filter out all rows in dataframe where T1_diff and T2_diff is greater than 3. In this scenario the output should only contain the second row as first row contains -5 as T1_Diff. targetList can contain more columns, currently it has T1_diff, T2_diff, if there is another column called T3_diff, so that should be automatically handled. 
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following `List` of columns which you want to filter out for a value greater than 3.

```
val lst = List("T1_diff", "T2_diff")
```

Then you can create a `String` using these column names and then pass that `String` to `where` function.

```
val condition = lst.map(c => s"$c>3").mkString(" AND ")
df.where(condition).show(false)
```

For the above Dataframe it will output only second row.

```
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
|Week      |Dim1|Dim2|T1_diff|T2_diff|
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
|2016-04-30|14  |FR  |90     |4      |
+----------+----+----+-------+-------+
```

If you have another column say `T3_diff` you can add it to the `List` and it will get added to the filter condition.